# Old Question about Cantrip Level is limited in scope

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

While this question: [How can I tell how many damage dice to roll for an NPCs cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123219/how-can-i-tell-how-many-damage-dice-to-roll-for-an-npcs-cantrip) does have a duplicate here: [At what level do monsters cast cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53800/at-what-level-do-monsters-cast-cantrips), the example for the older question limited the scope of the answers to Innate Spellcasting while the newer question is more comprehensive.

Should we reverse the duplicate for this reason?

Answer (score 9):

## Reverse!

While I do not agree that the question was limited in scope, the answer was limited in it's response. The questions do seem entirely identical, but your answer covers the full range of cases and is superior.

I'd recommend that Tiggerous' question become the primary and mark the older question as a duplicate.